How to Use BigQuery Views for Incremental Data Loading in BI Tools When They Can’t Utilize _TABLE_SUFFIX?
I’m currently working with Google BigQuery and a BI tool that handles incremental data loading automatically. In BigQuery, I have a partitioned table where each partition is represented by a _TABLE_SUFFIX. This _TABLE_SUFFIX is an integer value that represents the date of the partition (e.g., 20240402).
Previously, when using a custom script for incremental loading from BigQuery, I was able to provide the value of _TABLE_SUFFIX to limit the amount of processed data and make the query faster. This involved checking the latest _TABLE_SUFFIX value stored in my data warehouse and using that to query the new values of _TABLE_SUFFIX from BigQuery.
However, since moving to a new BI tool (Amazon QuickSight) that doesn’t provide the provision to do this, I’m stuck using a full reload every time. The incremental refresh in this new BI tool is handled automatically, and I just have to point it to which date field to use for that. However, _TABLE_SUFFIX in my case is an integer representing the date partitions of the table, and adding it to the select clause and casting it to a date will not help as the BI tool will try to set it as a date in the WHERE clause and this will fail.
I’m wondering if I can do this using views within BigQuery. However, I’m concerned that this might trigger a read through all partitions every time this view gets accessed.
Is there a way to use BigQuery views for incremental data loading in BI tools when they can’t utilize _TABLE_SUFFIX? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I'm confused with where are you loading data incrementally. Where are you getting the data from and where are you loading it to? X to BQ? BQ to BQ? BQ to QuickSight?

The data originates from Firebase and moved to BigQuery in a date-partitioned table (no concern here) and I load it incrementally from QuickSight.   however, for every query fired from QuickSight, BigQuery scans through all partitions of the table which is not efficient and will rack up cost.  and there is no way to make QS add _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN  to the where clause.  it works with date fields only.
